# JSF data binding

Tags: data-binding, jsf

I am having trouble using JSF just wanted to run it by so if there is anything obvious someone can spot. I have a managed bean which is giving me trouble. In my `faces-config.xml` I have:

```
<managed-bean>
  <description>Info Bean</description>
  <managed-bean-name>InfoBean</managed-bean-name>
  <managed-bean-class>bean.InfoBean</managed-bean-class>
  <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

In my JSF I have the following:

```
<h:outputText value="#{InfoBean.deviceModel}" rendered="true"></h:outputText>
```

I have a POJO for InfoBean as follows:

```
public class InfoBean {

String deviceModel;
String userEmail;
String active;

public InfoBean() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public String getDeviceModel() {
    return deviceModel;
}
public void setDeviceModel(String deviceModel) {
    this.deviceModel = deviceModel;
}
public String getUserEmail() {
    return userEmail;
}
public void setUserEmail(String userEmail) {
    this.userEmail = userEmail;
}
public String getActive() {
    return active;
}
public void setActive(String active) {
    this.active = active;
}
}
```

There is a no arg constructor in POJO too, but for some reason the deviceModel value does not get displayed to the screen and I cannot figure out why! Any help much appreciated. I have a handler which is also in the faces-config as a separate managed bean, when the user clicks a button, control goes to handler class which calls a service that populates fields in the POJO InfoBean, so as I can see it should appear but it does not!

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: It isn't a typo? bean.ImeiInfoBean != InfoBean

Comment: Sorry I just stripped out some name to preserve some confidential info and forgot that bit. There is no typo however.

Comment: How does the handler class acquire the reference to the InfoBean? I would check that it is the same instance that the field reads from. It is difficult to diagnose the problem without seeing the flow of events. Create a simple app that reduces the elements to the fewest required to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have sorted out the issue and the solution is that since I had a model like this: JSP button is clicked->call goes to Handler->handler calls method in service->Service populates the managed bean InfoBean and returns it to handler

The managed bean even though declared in the config file with scope as session was NOT actually part of the session. In my handler after returning the InfoBean I added:

```
HttpSession session = (HttpSession)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(false);
    session.setAttribute("InfoBean", InfoBean);
```

This placed it in the session and immediately and values started appearing! :-))

I  have read several articles about this and never seen this mentioned, so I am wondering how it is done otherwise. One other suggestion I got was make InfoBean a private instance of the Handler with getters and setters, this way it will get created with the handler and will also be olk. I have not tried this approach though. Thanks to all who helped.

Answer (score 0):

How your deviceModel property of the bean is populated?

Are you sure that it is not null? You can eventually check that by putting a log in the getter method:

```
public String getDeviceModel() {
    System.out.println("Getter called: " + deviceModel + ".");
    return deviceModel;
}
```

Eventually, you can modify the scope of the bean to set it as *session*.

Answer (score 0):

Your post shows it being defined in request scope not session scope. If you change it to session, you won't need put it in using setAttribute(). Or maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Despite changign the scope to session, it was not working, the above code where I add it to the HttpSession is necessary in order for this to work, or so I have found.

Thanks.